# How to get a websocket in glassfish 4 and jsf working?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, websocket, glassfish

Here's my code I get the js ws working but when y try to send a message to the websocket :glassfish returns:

```
INFO:   Error : SessionImpl{uri=/Formosa2/endpoint, id='b821d249-6435-45fe-812d- 577bc5fc8fca', endpoint=EndpointWrapper{endpointClass=null, endpoint=org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint@1602760, uri='/Formosa2/endpoint', contextPath='/Formosa2'}}

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/endpoint")
@Singleton
public class websocket {
private static Set<Session> peers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message) {
        String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s", message.toString());
        broadcast(filteredMessage);
        System.out.println(message);
}

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session peer){
    peers.add(peer);
    String message = String.format("* %s %s", "User has joined.");
    broadcast(message);
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session peer){
    peers.remove(peer);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Session aclientSession, Throwable aThrowable) {
    System.out.println("Error : " + aclientSession);
}

private void broadcast(String message) {
        for (Session peer : peers) {
            try {
                CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(message);
                peer.getBasicRemote().sendText(buffer.toString());
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
                // Ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

            ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/Formosa2/endpoint');  //Annotation

    ws.onopen = function(event) {
             Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
                    document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = function(event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                            sendMessage();
                        }
                    };
    };

    ws.onmessage = function(event) {
                sendMessage(event);
    };

    ws.onclose = function(event) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = null;
                    Console.log('Info: WebSocket closed.');
    };

    ws.onerror = function(event){
        alert("Error :  " + event.data);
                    Console.log(message.data);
    };


            function sendMessage (event) {
                var text = document.getElementById('form:texto').value;
                var select = document.getElementById('form:empresaidEmpresa');
                var text2 = document.getElementById('inicio_input').value;

                var name = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
                    ws.send(texto +', '+ name +',' + text2);
                    document.getElementById('chat').value = '';
            }

            var Console = {};

            Console.log = (function(message) {
                var console = document.getElementById('console');
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
                p.innerHTML = message;
                console.appendChild(p);
                while (console.childNodes.length > 25) {
                    console.removeChild(console.firstChild);
                }
                console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
            });

   //         Chat.initialize();

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String message = String.format("* %s %s", "User has joined.");
```

this line was the problem
format modifiers were incorret,I was able to discover that by reading in the log (system.out..) of the aThrowable parameter.

Comment: @OnError
public void onError(Session aclientSession, Throwable aThrowable) {
    System.out.println("Error : " + aclientSession); System.out.println("Error :" + aThrowable);
}

Comment: I still don't understand the solution -- it would be great if you could improve your answer and give more details on what was the problem and what you did to resolve it. Thanks!